# Class 'BaseController' not found in 'RouteController.php'

Tags: php, phpstorm

I started writing a site and encountered this problem. I created `RouteController`, which serves for address bar parsing, and created an inherited class to have a binding:

```
protected $controller;
protected $inputMethod;
protected $outputMethod;
protected $parameters;
```

Well, generally speaking, the base class, which is inherited by RouteController. But when I just added "extends BaseController" to "class RouteController", it immediately started crashing and outputted the following error:

> PHP Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Core\Base\Controllers\BaseController' not found in /var/www/Artemiys_Shop/Core/Base/Controllers/RouteController. php:10 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in /var/www/Artemiys_Shop/Core/Base/Controllers/RouteController.php on line 10

Does anyone know where I might have made a mistake or done something wrong? I've never had a problem with this before.

RouteController.php

```
<?php

namespace Core\Base\Controllers;

use Core\Base\Exceptions\RouteException;
use Core\Base\Settings\Settings;
use Core\Base\Settings\ShopSettings;


class RouteController extends BaseController
{

    static private $_instance;

    protected $routes;

    private function _clone()
    {
    }

    static public function getInstance()
    {
        if(self::$_instance instanceof self){
            return self::$_instance;
        }
        return self::$_instance = new self;
    }

    /**
     * @throws RouteException
     */

    private function _construct()
    {

        $address_str = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

        if(strpos($address_str, '/') === strlen($address_str) - 1 && strpos($address_str, '/') !== 0){
            $this->redirect(rtrim($address_str, '/'), 301);
        }

        $path = substr($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'], 0, strpos($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'], 'index.php'));

        if($path === PATH){
            $this->routes = Settings::get('routes');
            if(!$this->routes) throw new RouteException('Website is under maintenance');
            $url = explode('/', substr($address_str, strlen(PATH)));
            if($url[0] && $url[0] === $this->routes['admin']['alias']){
                array_shift($url);
                if($url[0] && is_dir($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . PATH . $this->routes['plugins']['path'] . $url[0])){
                    $plugin = array_shift($url);
                    $pluginSettings = $this->routes['settings']['path'] . ucfirst($plugin . 'Settings');
                    if(file_exists($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . PATH . $pluginSettings . '.php')){
                        $pluginSettings = str_replace('/', '\\', $pluginSettings);
                        $this->routes = $pluginSettings::get('routes');
                    }
                    $dir = $this->routes['plugins']['dir'] ? '/' . $this->routes['plugins']['dir'] . '/' : '/';
                    $dir = str_replace('//', '/', $dir);
                    $this->controller = $this->routes['plugins']['path'] . $plugin . $dir;
                    $hrUrl = $this->routes['plugins']['hrUrl'];
                    $route = 'plugins';
                }else{
                    $this->controller = $this->routes['admin']['path'];
                    $hrUrl = $this->routes['admin']['hrUrl'];
                    $route = 'admin';
                }
            }else{
                $hrUrl = $this->routes['user']['hrUrl'];
                $this->controller = $this->routes['user']['path'];
                $route = 'user';
            }
            $this->createRoute($route, $url);
            if($url[1]){
                $count = count($url);
                $key = '';
                if(!$hrUrl){
                   $i = 1;
                }else{
                    $this->parameters['alias'] = $url[1];
                    $i = 2;
                }
                for( ; $i < $count; $i++){
                    if(!$key){
                        $key = $url[$i];
                        $this->parameters[$key] = '';
                    }else{
                        $this->parameters[$key] = $url[$i];
                        $key = '';
                    }
                }
            }

            exit();
        }else{
            try{
                throw new \Exception('Incorrect directory');
            }
            catch (\Exception $e){
                exit($e->getMessage());
            }
        }

    }

    private function createRoute($var, $arr){
        $route = [];
        if(!empty($arr[0])){
            if($this->routes[$var]['routes'][$arr[0]]){
                $route = explode('/', $this->routes[$var]['routes'][$arr[0]]);
                $this->controller .= ucfirst($route[0]. 'Controller');
            }else{
                $this->controller .= ucfirst($arr[0]. 'Controller');
            }
        }else{
            $this->controller .= $this->routes['default']['controller'];
        }
        $this->inputMethod = $route[1] ? $route[1] : $this->routes['default']['inputMethod'];
        $this->outputMethod = $route[2] ? $route[2] : $this->routes['default']['outputMethod'];

        return;
    }

}
```

BaseController.php

```
<?php


namespace Core\Base\Controllers;

use Core\Base\Exceptions\RouteException;

abstract class BaseController
{

    protected $controller;
    protected $inputMethod;
    protected $outputMethod;
    protected $parameters;


    /**
     * @throws RouteException
     */

    public function route() {
        $controller = str_replace('/', '\\', $this->controller);
        try {
            $object = new \ReflectionMethod($controller, 'request');
            $args = [
                'parameters' => $this->parameters,
                'inputMethod' => $this->inputMethod,
                'outputMethod' => $this->outputMethod
            ];
            $object->invoke(new $controller, $args);
        }
        catch (\ReflectionException $e){
            throw new RouteException($e->getMessage());
        }
    }
    public function request($args){

    }

}
```

Index.php

```
<?php

define ('VG_ACCESS', true);

header('Content-Type:text/html;charset=utf-8');
session_start();

require_once 'config.php';
require_once 'Core/Base/Settings/internal_settings.php';

use Core\Base\Exceptions\RouteException;
use Core\Base\Controllers\RouteController;


try{
    RouteController::getInstance()->route();
}
catch (RouteException $e) {
    exit($e->getMessage());
}
```

Setting.php

```
<?php


namespace Core\Base\Settings;


class Settings
{

    static private $_instance;

    private array $routes = [
        'admin' => [
            'alias' => 'admin',
            'path' => 'Core/Admin/Controllers/',
            'hrUrl' => false
        ],
        'settings' => [
            'path' => 'Core/Base/Settings/'
        ],
        'plugins' => [
            'path' => 'Core/Plugins/',
            'hrUrl' => false,
            'dir' => false
        ],
        'user' => [
            'path' => 'Core/User/Controllers/',
            'hrUrl' => true,
            'routes' => [

            ]
        ],
        'default' => [
            'controller' => 'IndexController',
            'inputMethod' => 'inputData',
            'outputMethod' => 'outputData'
        ]
    ];
```

[image: Directories]

[image: WebPage]

And i would like to know, why is this error showing up?

Comment: Show how you are running it (the screenshot). Right now it looks like you are trying to execute this Controller class directly and therefore bypassing your framework / bootstrap logic (which inlcudes class autoloading part). If that's so -- it's expected. You need to run it "normally" via your entry point script (index.php as I understand).

Comment: This all could be because you just hit "Run" button that executes the file directly in CLI environment ("PHP Script" type of Run/Debug Configuration). If it meant to be executed in a browser (most likely) then you need a different type of Run/Debug Configuration (which you can easily create manually .. or just type the right URL in your browser). **Anyway:** more details is needed on how you run it and how you want it to be executed.

Comment: @LazyOne i'm running it from my local server apache (If you about it). I've added a screenshot what going on while i'm openning my website. I just wonder if it's a problem with this code (method) or if I'm connecting it all wrong.

Comment: 1) What is the URL in the address bar? So that I have some better idea on how you are doing it. 2) Do you have any class autoloading code anywhere? I.e. Do you use Composer .. or some another (your framework) class loader? Or perhaps you are using `require`/`include` for you classes?

Comment: The point I'm trying to make here: your PHP is unaware of the `BaseController` which means that it was not loaded before executing that `RouteController` .. which clearly suggests that you may not have class loading  / require in place. Just in case: the `use XXX` lines will not load the class for you -- they are just references so that you can use short class name instead of FQN.